# Cómo puedo hacer para alternar mayúsculas hasta el final de la palabra (Python)

Tags: python, string

Dada una palabra, digamos "Perro" el resultado debe ser
Perro
pErro
peRro
perRo
perrO

El código que tengo funciona pero para palabras cortas, si pongo alguna palabra más larga ya no, alguien que me pueda ayudar?

```
palabra = 'perro'
new_palabra = ""
contador = 0

for i in range(len(palabra)):
  
    palabra = palabra.lower()
   
    new_palabra = palabra.replace(palabra[contador], palabra[contador].upper())
    print(new_palabra)
   
    contador +=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acá te dejo un ejemplo que utiliza string slice y list comprehension:

```
palabra = "DisparateDePalabraLargisima"
p = palabra.lower()

palabras = [p[:i] + p[i].upper() + p[i+1:] for i in range(len(p))]
```

Devuelve:

```
'Disparatedepalabralargisima', 'dIsparatedepalabralargisima', 'diSparatedepalabralargisima', 'disParatedepalabralargisima', 'dispAratedepalabralargisima', 'dispaRatedepalabralargisima', 'disparAtedepalabralargisima', 'disparaTedepalabralargisima', 'disparatEdepalabralargisima', 'disparateDepalabralargisima', 'disparatedEpalabralargisima', 'disparatedePalabralargisima', 'disparatedepAlabralargisima', 'disparatedepaLabralargisima', 'disparatedepalAbralargisima', 'disparatedepalaBralargisima', 'disparatedepalabRalargisima', 'disparatedepalabrAlargisima', 'disparatedepalabraLargisima', 'disparatedepalabralArgisima', 'disparatedepalabralaRgisima', 'disparatedepalabralarGisima', 'disparatedepalabralargIsima', 'disparatedepalabralargiSima', 'disparatedepalabralargisIma', 'disparatedepalabralargisiMa', 'disparatedepalabralargisimA'
```

Comment: Y usando un .join() ?

Comment: la respuesta de Candid Moe ya usa `''.join()`

Comment: Si, lo sé. Pero una comprensión de lista me parece más elegante, aunque la de Candid es más explicita. Lo decía también porque en teoría .join() es más eficiente que el operador por las optimizaciones que ya implementa python para el método.

Comment: Para hacer join tienes que declarar variables y no puedes hacerlo al interno de una comprensión de lista. Por este motivo usando slicing es 8 veces más rápido aunque no use `''.join()`. Hice ejecutar 100 veces las dos respuestas y slice es el método más rápido, 0 milisegundos vs 8 milisegundos que toma usando join

Comment: Puedes usar join dentro de la comprensión, sin variables intermedias: `["".join((p[:i], p[i].upper(), p[i+1:])) for i in range(len(p))]` otra cosa es que sea más rápido o más legible (que lo dudo)

Comment: Si, eso mismo acabo de hacer y el uso del operador es más rapido sorprendentemente. Ahora pongo una respuesta con el código

Comment: Lo he chequeado y join usado de esa manera enlentece el proceso.

Comment: Eso es, he publicado mi respuesta con eso mismo. Lo que no entiendo es "por qué", ya que el consenso general en la red es no usar el operador "+" cuando se juntan cadenas de texto. Esto me recuerda de que siempre hay que medir el rendimiento de tu código a pesar de lo que creas conocer.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que pasa es que `replace` opera sobre toda la cadena. Si dices `replace('A', 'B')`, todas las letras `A` presentes en la cadena serán reemplazadas por la letra `B`.

Una solución es recorrer la cadena reemplazando por posición, así:

```
palabra = list("SuperCalifraquilisticoEspianidoso")

for i in range(len(palabra)):
    original = palabra[i]
    palabra[i] = original.upper()
    print(''.join(palabra))
    palabra[i] = original
```

La palabra la convertimos en lista para poder reemplazar los caracteres dentro del ciclo `for`.

Primero guardamos el caracter original (hay que dejarlo cual estaba antes) y lo reemplazamos con la versión en mayúsculas.

Usando `join` juntamos todas las letras en una sola cadena, la que imprimimos.

Luego volvemos a dejar el caracter original tal cual estaba.

El código produce:

```
SuperCalifraquilisticoEspianidoso
SUperCalifraquilisticoEspianidoso
SuPerCalifraquilisticoEspianidoso
SupErCalifraquilisticoEspianidoso
SupeRCalifraquilisticoEspianidoso
SuperCalifraquilisticoEspianidoso
SuperCAlifraquilisticoEspianidoso
SuperCaLifraquilisticoEspianidoso
SuperCalIfraquilisticoEspianidoso
SuperCaliFraquilisticoEspianidoso
SuperCalifRaquilisticoEspianidoso
SuperCalifrAquilisticoEspianidoso
SuperCalifraQuilisticoEspianidoso
SuperCalifraqUilisticoEspianidoso
SuperCalifraquIlisticoEspianidoso
SuperCalifraquiListicoEspianidoso
SuperCalifraquilIsticoEspianidoso
SuperCalifraquiliSticoEspianidoso
SuperCalifraquilisTicoEspianidoso
SuperCalifraquilistIcoEspianidoso
SuperCalifraquilistiCoEspianidoso
SuperCalifraquilisticOEspianidoso
SuperCalifraquilisticoEspianidoso
SuperCalifraquilisticoESpianidoso
SuperCalifraquilisticoEsPianidoso
SuperCalifraquilisticoEspIanidoso
SuperCalifraquilisticoEspiAnidoso
SuperCalifraquilisticoEspiaNidoso
SuperCalifraquilisticoEspianIdoso
SuperCalifraquilisticoEspianiDoso
SuperCalifraquilisticoEspianidOso
SuperCalifraquilisticoEspianidoSo
SuperCalifraquilisticoEspianidosO
```

Answer (score 0):

A raiz de los comentarios en la respuesta de Ariel he escrito la misma version pero con el método `join()` y los resultados muestran que el uso del operador en este caso es más rápido:

```
from statistics import mean
from time import perf_counter_ns

palabra = "DisparateDePalabraLargisima"
palabra_candid = list("SuperCalifraquilisticoEspianidoso".lower()) # Necesita las minúsculas también

operador = list()
metodo = list()
metodo_candid = list()

p = palabra.lower()


for _ in range(1000):
    t0 = perf_counter_ns()
    palabras = [p[:i] + p[i].upper() + p[i + 1 :] for i in range(len(p))]
    t1 = perf_counter_ns()
    operador.append(t1 - t0)

for _ in range(1000):
    t0 = perf_counter_ns()
    palabras2 = ["".join([p[:i], p[i].upper(), p[i + 1 :]]) for i in range(len(p))]
    t1 = perf_counter_ns()
    metodo.append(t1 - t0)

for _ in range(1000):
    t0 = perf_counter_ns()
    for i in range(len(palabra_candid)):
        original = palabra_candid[i]
        palabra_candid[i] = original.upper()
        palabras3 = ''.join(palabra_candid)
        palabra_candid[i] = original
    t1 = perf_counter_ns()
    metodo_candid.append(t1 - t0)

print("Operador {0}ns".format(mean(operador)))
print("Método {0}ns".format(mean(metodo)))
print("Método Candid {0}".format(mean(metodo_candid)))
```

> Operador 7970.121ns
>
> Método 8587.779ns
>
> Método Candid 15759.757ns

Lo cual me resulta extraño puesto que en teoría el método `join()` debería ser más eficiente en cuanto a cadenas de texto se refiere y creo que tiene que ver con la forma en que el bucle se ejecuta a nivel máquina.

De cualquier forma la diferencia entre una palabra más larga que la otra no es muy significativa. así que pienso que cualquier forma seria válida.

PS. He añadido también la solución de @CandidMoe y es prácticamente el doble de lenta que la solución de @Ariel. Le he añadido a su código las minúsculas que no incorporaba y no respetaba el mismo output de la pregunta

Comment: Creo que la diferencia de tiempo se debe a que en el segundo método tienes que crear una lista para pasar los parámetros al join.

Comment: Además (y este es el detalle más importante), join es solo más eficaz que la concatenación en el caso de que puedas hacer `''.join(lista)` porque evita que tengas que llamar cada índice de la lista para concatenarlo de este modo `lista[0]+lista[1]` pero desde el momento en que decides hacer `''.join( [ lista[0] + lista[1] ] )` el uso de join no cumple su objetivo ya que tiene que acceder a los índices para unir la lista.

Comment: He probado también con `itemgetter` pero el código es más lento y más confuso. No se me ocurre ninguna forma de que sea más eficiente.

Comment: A mi me parece que un código que se ejecuta mil veces en cuestión de milisegundos ya es bastante eficiente :)

Answer (score -3):

Una solución:

```py
p = "SuperCalifraquilisticoEspianidoso"
pp = [p[:i] + p[i].upper() + p[i+1:] for i in range(len(p))]
print(*pp, sep='\n')
```

Comment: Considera explicar cómo tu código puede ayudar

Comment: Estamos en [es.so], por favor los comentarios en castellano. Responder sólo con código se considera de baja calidad, por favor leer [answer].